# Schedule talks in tracks

Tags: c#, comparative-review, interface

Consider my simple business requirement as follows:

There is a list of *talk*s and they need to be scheduled in *track*s. Each track has a morning session starting at 9am and an afternoon session starting at 1pm ending by 4pm and a lunch break from 12pm to 1pm.

Given: A list of talks - Talk.txt

> Python session 90min
> Java session 75min
> Blender session 120min

When: I call by business implementation

Then: It gives the list of scheduled track

> Track 1:
>
> 9:00am Python session
>
> 10:30am Java session
>
> 12:00pm Lunch
>
> 1:00pm Blender session

Now to approach this problem I want to design a contract that expect to return the final result. Besides I'm thinking some of the future (or possible) business requirement changes.

1. Presentation of the schedule has changed to "Java session at 10:30am"
2. In above expected output there is a gap of 15 mins between lunch and the previous talk
3. Perhaps the morning session's start time has changed to 10am

The simplest way to designing the contract that I have in my mind is:

```
public interface IScheduleTalk
{
    List<string> GetScheduledTalk(List<string> usrInput)
}
```

But it does not help me with the above problems, and then I have change the contract if any the requirement changes in above mentioned way. Besides it does not address the gap.

I went to redesign my contract and have come up with below two approaches:

1st being:

```
public class Track
{
    public int TrackNumber { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<Slot, string> ScheduledTalks { get; set; }
}

public class Slot
{
    public string ScheduledTime { get; set; }
    public int DurationInMin { get; set; }
}

public interface IScheduleTalk
{
    List<Track> GetScheduledTalk(List<string> talks); 
}
```

And the 2nd is:

```
public class Track
{
    public int TrackNumber { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Talk> ScheduledTalks { get; set; } //Dictionary TKey represents the schedule time such as "9:00am"
}

public class Talk
{
    public int DurationInMin {get; set;}
    public string TalkName {get; set;}
}

public interface IScheduleTalk
{
    List<Track> GetScheduledTalk(List<string> talks); 
}
```

I need a suggestion which one should I use as the contract. Or if there is/are better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I see what you are trying to achieve, while your question does not fully meet the Code Review rules, but I guess some inputs won't hurt specially in my free time ;).

In my opinion,

- You should use `DateTime` instead of `string` and `int`.
- You should combine `Talk` and `Slot`, as it should be only one class that hold the meeting details (subject, time, and place ..etc).
- You can use `DurationInMin`, but I would rather use `DateTime` and based on the business requirements, I would make a way to make the user input only integer while using `DateTime` in the back-end, (e.g. in the front-end, I make a field that only accepts int, and in the back-end, I call `DateTime.AddMinutes()`) this way, if the business logic required (in the future) to add meetings for future reference (such as making a meeting schedule for the next day or week ..etc), it'll be easy to adjust without being a break change.
- `Dictionary<Slot, string>` should be `Dictionary<int, Slot>` the int will represent the TrackNumber, which will remove the need of `TrackNumber`.
- GetScheduledTalk takes `List<string>` and return `List<Track>`, doesn't make any sense to me! using string list in this situation will be a real pain. Even if is it an input that you get from another resource (such as CVS). if there is any serialization process in this part, I would suggest moving it to a handler class, and create a model for it, then change the string to that model.

Finally, **Naming Convention**, you should keep your objects names clearer by naming each object to its rule. if the object is related to another object, then include the name of that object as well.

Here is a proposal that might help you in your implementation.

```
public enum ScheduleSessionName
{
    Python,
    Java,
    Blender
}

public class ScheduleSessionSlot
{
    public ScheduleSessionName SessionName { get; set; }

    public DateTime SessionTimeStart { get; set; }

    public DateTime SessionTimeEnd { get; set; }

    //you can use this method if you want to make SessionTimeEnd readonly property, so it will be automatically set with def
    public DateTime SetDefaultSessionTime(DateTime sessionTimeStart)
    {
        switch (SessionName)
        {
            case ScheduleSessionName.Python:
                return sessionTimeStart.AddMinutes(90);
            case ScheduleSessionName.Java:
                return sessionTimeStart.AddMinutes(75);
            case ScheduleSessionName.Blender:
                return sessionTimeStart.AddMinutes(120);
            default:
                return sessionTimeStart.AddMinutes(60);
        }

    }

}

public interface ISchedule : IEnumerable
{      
    int Count { get; }

    void Add(int trackNumber, ScheduleSessionSlot sessionSlot);

    void Remove(int trackNumber);

    void Clear();

    new IEnumerator GetEnumerator();

}


public class Schedule : ISchedule
{

    private readonly Dictionary<int, ScheduleSessionSlot> _schedulesStore = new Dictionary<int, ScheduleSessionSlot>();

    public int Count => _schedulesStore.Count;

    public ICollection<int> TrackNumbers => _schedulesStore.Keys;

    public ICollection<ScheduleSessionSlot> SessionSlots => _schedulesStore.Values;

    public ScheduleSessionSlot this[int trackNumber]
    {
        get => _schedulesStore.ContainsKey(trackNumber) ? _schedulesStore[trackNumber] : null;
        set => _schedulesStore[trackNumber] = value;
    }


    public void Add(int trackNumber, ScheduleSessionSlot sessionSlot) => _schedulesStore.Add(trackNumber, sessionSlot);

    public void Remove(int trackNumber) => _schedulesStore.Remove(trackNumber);

    public bool Contains(int trackNumber) => _schedulesStore.ContainsKey(trackNumber);

    public bool Contains(ScheduleSessionSlot sessionSlot) => _schedulesStore.ContainsValue(sessionSlot);

    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<int, ScheduleSessionSlot> schedule) => _schedulesStore.Contains(schedule);

    public void Clear() => _schedulesStore.Clear();

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() => _schedulesStore.GetEnumerator();

}
```

The rest, will require your action ;).

Comment: What Is covered by `ISchedule` that Is not covered by `IDictionary<int, ScheduleSessionSlot>`?

Comment: @slepic I see your point, I didn't catch it ;).. I have updated the code. thanks for the catch

Comment: When a question doesn't fully meet the code review guidelines you might want to hold off on answering it. There are 3 votes to close the question.

Comment: I dont think you understood me. I wanted to say the `ISchedule` interface is useless as it basically renames the methods of the dictionary and does not do anything more than a dictionary. Therefore IDictionary<int, ScheduleSessionSlot> is completely satisfactory.

Comment: @slepic this is just an example, and if the OP took it as is, then yes, I totally agree with you. But I placed it for demonstration purpose and not intended to be a completed solution.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Roger that !